# Random Prime generator

Tags: java, primes

I have this method that will give a random prime for a given range (min inclusive an max not inclusive) all comments are welcome:

```
public static int randomPrime(int min, int max) {
    if (min < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("min must be positive.");
    if (min >= max)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("min must be smaller the max.");
    if (!containsPrime(min,max))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no Primes in this interval.");
    if (rand == null) {
        rand = new Random();
    }
    int out = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    while (!isPrime(out)) {
        out = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    }
    return out;
}
    private static boolean containsPrime(int min, int max) {
    if (isPrime(min)||isPrime(max-1)){
        return true;
    }
    if(min%2==0){
        min +=1;
    }
    while (min<max){
        if (isPrime(min)){
            return true;
        }
        min +=2;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to share your `isPrime` method as well?

Comment: If this is for cryptography purposes (where random prime numbers are used a lot), you may want to have your random number generator be injectable (`Random` may not be good enough).  You're vulnerable to integer overflow; depending on the starting values of `min`/`max` (and the implementation of `isPrime()`), you could spin through all negative numbers.  There's probably at least one additional optimization for the prime range-check, something about 3 prime numbers every 100 or something (I can't remember exactly what it was, though).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think you missed my input validation,  the code is pure for statistics, no worries about Random i am using a specialised version there.

Comment: Argh, I forgot that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is odd - if it were even, you would be.  Other things - the even/odd check can be performed first, before the initial check for primeness of min/max.  Move `min += 2;` above the prime check in the `while (min < max)` loop - you check the 'initial' min value twice.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647, is not just odd... it's a prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use some white space. The scrunched expressions are harder to read. At a minimum, I recommend spaces around every operator.

In `containsPrime`, if the variable `min` is odd, then it gets checked twice. You can replace the second if block with this:

```
if (min % 2 == 0) min += 1;
else min += 2;
```

Comment: and while we're at it, `min += 1` can and should be `min++`

Comment: That if-else statement can be reduced to a ternary to save a line: `min += (min % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;`.

Comment: I am not a fan of ternary's so i'll stick to the suggestion of Donald on this one, but Thx,to both of you for the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 4):

```
int out = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
while (!isPrime(out)) {
    out = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
}
return out;
```

This duplicate code can be replaced with a do/while loop. The rule of thumb is, if you always need to perform an action at least once, do while!

```
int out;
do {
    out = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
} while(!isPrime(out));
return out;
```